# (SQL) Transposing rows to column using RANK OVER returns only one occurence out of two indentical entries

Tags: sql, transpose, rank

I am using oracle embedded HR.JOB_DETAILS table.
I would like all entries to appear after transposing rows to columns for columns departmet_id and job_id, but for one value (ST_CLERK) for department_id=50 source table has got 2 entries, but occurs only once in final result.

Subquery queries for min value of particular trasnposed columns - that is clear. But I can't find solution to return both occurences.

Source table:

[image: Source table]

Query used:

```
select a, b, c, d, e, f from (
select min("20") a, min("50") b, min ("60") c, min ("80") d, min("90") e, min("110") f from (
      select 
case when department_id=20 then job_id end as "20" ,
case when department_id=50 then job_id end as "50" ,
case when department_id=60 then job_id end as "60" ,
case when department_id=80 then job_id end as "80" ,
case when department_id=90 then job_id end as "90" ,
case when department_id=110 then job_id end as "110",
rank() over (partition by department_id order by job_id) as row_num
from job_history) x
group by row_num);
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()` instead:

```
row_number() over (partition by department_id order by job_id) as row_num
```

`rank()` returns the same value for duplicates, which the `group by` will combine into a single row.  `row_number()` is guaranteed to return a different value, so they will not be combined.